# Why do I have to restart VS Code every time I want to run my code with the latest (saved) changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I just started having this problem a few hours ago, and before that I never had this issue.

I am writing a code in Julia using VS Code also using Julia Repl and Revise. Since a few hours every time I make a change in the code I have to restart VS Code to be able to run my recently saved code. Otherwise, if I do not restart the code, terminal just tells that it is finished and the code ran already, which actually did not happen.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, or what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to save it different ways, and searched for similar problem online, but did not really find anything useful.

Comment: do you still get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What if you restart the REPL inside the VSCode instead of restarting the whole program?
For this, you can use this key shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>. Also, you can find it using <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> and the search for `Restart REPL`.
For me, however, this didn't happen unless I wrote the code so it couldn't be mutated after the first run. For example, I can't redefine a composite type in Julia, and I do need to restart the Julia session to do it.